# Each not working on array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all form input elements and iterate through them, unfortunately `Each` iterator do not work. I have checked the `$inputs` variable and it has 5 elements in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script>
$(document).on('click', '#test-endpoint', function () {
    var $form = $(this).parents('#test-form').first();
    var $inputs = $form.find('input, textarea');

    $inputs.each(function () {
    //The code never executed
    });
}
</script>

<form action="http://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test-form">

    <input type="button" name="submitButton" id="test-endpoint" value="Submit1">

    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Endpoints</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            POST   http://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Authentication</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Parameter</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Authentication</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <strong>ApiKey</strong>
                            <p>Optional</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong>String</strong>
                            <p>API Key should be passed if you purchased membership with credits. Please login to your control panel to find out your API Key http://www.convertapi.com/a</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="ApiKey" placeholder="Optional">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Parameters</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Parameter</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong>File</strong>
                                <p>Required</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Binary</strong>
                                <p>Supported source file formats.</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <input type="file" name="File">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong>DocumentTitle</strong>
                                <p>Optional</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>String</strong>
                                <p>Set the title of the generated Pdf file. If value is not set a source document title is used instead.</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="DocumentTitle" placeholder="Optional">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong>DocumentSubject</strong>
                                <p>Optional</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>String</strong>
                                <p>Set the subject of the generated Pdf file. If value is not set a source document subject is used instead.</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="DocumentSubject" placeholder="Optional">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Output</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="test-output" class="panel-body">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I use jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: It should work, could you show your html markup?

Comment: as a side not `var $form = $(this).parents('#test-form').first();` can be replaced with `var $form = $('#test-form');`

Comment: if you have multiple forms then use class instead of id because id has to be unique, then use .closest() like `var $form = $(this).closest('.test-form');`

Comment: @Anton I have posted full html.

Comment: You have a typo on your delegation.

Comment: Can you add `console.log($inputs);` before the $.each, and also add `console.log($(this));` inside the $.each. And yes, I know that you checked but maybe you checked wrong, or the error could be in your code in $.each not the $.each itself

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. It seems Chrome debug console do not step into Each iteration while using F10, I am VS developer and then I use F10 in VS it is always stepping into Iterations. The code works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding it with `$(document).ready()`, like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  var $form = $(this).parents('#test-form').first();
  var $inputs = $form.find('input, textarea');

  $inputs.each(function () {
    //The code never executed
  });

});
```

Probably your elements do not exist when you call the .each?

Comment: The `$inputs` element contains 5 elements as stated in the question

Comment: Yes but I thought maybe he was checking the $inputs manually later in the console, which would seem to work, because he probably checks in the console when the page is loaded.

Comment: And the console is oddly semi-live, unlike a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `)`

```
$(document).on('click', '#test-endpoint', function () {
    var $form = $'#test-form');
    var $inputs = $form.find('input, textarea');

    console.log($inputs.get());

    $inputs.each(function () {
        console.log(this)
    //The code never executed
    });
});//missing ) here
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SzxtG/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code as quoted has a syntax error, I can't see how you would ever see `$inputs` having anything:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test-endpoint', function () {
    var $form = $(this).parents('#test-form').first();
    var $inputs = $form.find('input, textarea');

    $inputs.each(function () {
      alert("Got: " + this.tagName);
    });
}  // <================= Missing ); here
```

[Here's your original code live](http://jsbin.com/gegiwamu/1/edit), which doesn't work.

[Here's a copy with `);` added](http://jsbin.com/gegiwamu/2/edit), which does work.

In your web console, there will be an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code:

```
var $form = $(this).parents('#test-form').first();
var $inputs = $form.find('input, textarea');

$inputs.each(function (  idx, value) {
//The code never executed
});
```